# c++ check input read from file with fail

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple program to read a series of integers from file and output their sum. I am to make sure that the input is indeed an integer, and exit the program if it isn't. 
I think I am doing everything right, but the program won't break when it is given invalid input. I am testing this with a file containing:    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 bla 9 
Is there something I am not seeing here?

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
     ifstream dataFile;
     int number, total = 0;

     if (argc < 2) { cout << "You forgot to specify the file name." << endl; exit(-1);}

    dataFile.open(argv[1]);

    while (dataFile>>number){
        if(dataFile.fail()) {cout<< "Found a not number"<<endl; exit(-2);}
        else total += number;
    }

    cout << total << endl;
    dataFile.close();
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: In the loop `dataFile.fail()` will never return `true`. In fact the loop condition is, basically, that `dataFile.good()` is `true` which is mutually exclusive with `dataFile.fail()` being `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is bad,  the [condition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/) of the while loop will [fail](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/)

```
while (dataFile>>number){  // will fail
```

Hence the programme will never reach this line with such an error state:

```
if(dataFile.fail())
```

You can try:

```
while (datafile >> number){  // loop until problem
    total += number;
}
if (dataFile.fail() && !datafile.eof()) {   // if problem is bad input
    cout << "Found a not number" << endl; 
    exit(-2);                               // then stop
}
```